# Visual Studio 2010 multi-screen layout keeps resetting

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I started a new job a few weeks ago.
In my previous job, I was working with 2 screens. I know have 3 screens here (what an upgrade!)

I have always been bothered by a small bug, and since today I don't have a lot of code to do, I decided to finally try to solve this problem. The layout I want to achieve is pretty simple (see screenshots below): One file on the left screen, and another one on the right.

What happens is the following:

- When I enter debug mode, the layout stays the same except one thing... the separation between two files (which is usually right between the two screens). Annoying for breakpoints and stuff, so I resize it, debug, and...
- When I leave debug mode and go back to debug, the layout go back to what it was... except the separation which moved as well!
- And last but not least, if I close Visual Studio and open it again, my two file views are now expanded on both screens, separated horizontally *(<- this one is new, I had never seen that before)*.

Every time I go to debug mode, or go back to design, I would resize it to fit my two screens. And then it would shift again at the next debug. After some time it shifts with a smaller amount of pixels. Then, it just stops shifting, as if it learned that it shouldn't change. Until at some point, it goes back to normal and forces me to resize again.

I tried to use add-ons such as **Perspectives** or **Layout O Rama** , but they didn't keep any information about the two Code windows. No matter how I was saving them (let's say, one would be 20% of the left screen, and the other would expand on 2 screens), it would ANYWAY go back to the strange, shifted layout.
I also tried **Visual Studio Productivity Power Tool** and it's terrible. If I dock a code tab as a Window on my second screen, and dock for example the Find Results on it, it would be separated or reorganized every time I switch to Debug/Design

Has anyone experienced that yet? Am I the only one feeling that my Visual Studio is a pet who will learn how to do his own layout as time goes?

Thank you!

Also, as an image is always better than a description, here are a few screenshots:

**Here, the normal, regular layout, with the red line being where my screens stop. Perfect, al dente layout allowing me to use the best of my two screens**

[image: This is the normal layout]

**Here, the one happening every time I go to debug. Notice how ONLY the code windows shifted (the bottom part with error list on the left and find results on the right didn't change at all )**

[image: This is the WTF one]

**And this is the one I get when I restart my IDE, forcing me to recreate my layout all the time**

[image: And the one on restart]

Thanks a lot!